# How to solve The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint error?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, migration, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to learn Clean Architecture, and I have a project related to it. I'm sharing the code below, and I'm getting this migration error : The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_UserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "LinguaSphereDB", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.

**ApplicationContextSeed.cs:
**

```
using LinguaSphere.Core.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace LinguaSphere.Persistence.Context.Seeds.Application
{
    public static class ApplicationContextSeed
    {
        static readonly Guid englishGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        static readonly Guid turkishGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        static readonly Guid frenchGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

        public static void ApplicationSeed(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            CreateLanguage(modelBuilder);
            CreateEvent(modelBuilder);
        }

        private static void CreateEvent(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            List<Event> events = EventList();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Event>().HasData(events);
        }

        private static void CreateLanguage(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            List<Language> languages = LanguageList();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Language>().HasData(languages);
        }

        private static List<Language> LanguageList()
        {
            return new List<Language>()
            {
                new Language() {LanguageID = turkishGuid, LanguageName = "Turkish", ShortLanguageName = "TR"},
                new Language() {LanguageID = englishGuid, LanguageName = "English", ShortLanguageName = "EN"},
                new Language() {LanguageID = frenchGuid, LanguageName = "French", ShortLanguageName = "FR"},
            };
        }

        private static List<Event> EventList()
        {
            return new List<Event>()
            {
                new Event() {EventID = Guid.NewGuid(), Date = DateTime.Now, LanguageID = turkishGuid, Name = "Turkish Lesson 1", Description = "Turkce'ye Giris 1"},
                new Event() {EventID = Guid.NewGuid(), Date = DateTime.Now, LanguageID = turkishGuid, Name = "Turkish Lesson 2", Description = "Turkce'ye Giris 2"},
                new Event() {EventID = Guid.NewGuid(), Date = DateTime.Now, LanguageID = turkishGuid, Name = "Turkish Lesson 3", Description = "Turkce'ye Giris 3"},
                new Event() {EventID = Guid.NewGuid(), Date = DateTime.Now, LanguageID = englishGuid, Name = "English Lesson 1", Description = "Introduction to English 1"},
                new Event() {EventID = Guid.NewGuid(), Date = DateTime.Now, LanguageID = englishGuid, Name = "English Lesson 2", Description = "Introduction to English 2"},
                new Event() {EventID = Guid.NewGuid(), Date = DateTime.Now, LanguageID = englishGuid, Name = "English Lesson 3", Description = "Introduction to English 3"},
                new Event() {EventID = Guid.NewGuid(), Date = DateTime.Now, LanguageID = frenchGuid, Name = "French Lesson 1", Description = "Introduction Au Français 1"},
                new Event() {EventID = Guid.NewGuid(), Date = DateTime.Now, LanguageID = frenchGuid, Name = "French Lesson 2", Description = "Introduction Au Français 2"},
                new Event() {EventID = Guid.NewGuid(), Date = DateTime.Now, LanguageID = frenchGuid, Name = "French Lesson 3", Description = "Introduction Au Français 3"},
            };
        }

    }
}
```

**IdentityContextSeed.cs:
**

```
using LinguaSphere.Core.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;

namespace LinguaSphere.Persistence.Context.Seeds.Identity
{
    public static class IdentityContextSeed
    {
        private static string idGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        private static string idGuid2 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        public static void IdentitySeed(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            CreateRoles(modelBuilder);
            CreateBasicUsers(modelBuilder);
            MapUserRole(modelBuilder);
        }

        private static void CreateRoles(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            List<IdentityRole> roles = IdentityRoleList();
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(roles);
        }

        private static void CreateBasicUsers(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            List<ApplicationUser> users = IdentityBasicUserList();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasData(users);
        }

        private static void MapUserRole(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var identityUserRoles = IdentityUserRoleList();
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(identityUserRoles);
        }
        private static List<IdentityRole> IdentityRoleList()
        {
            return new List<IdentityRole>()
            {
                new IdentityRole
                {
                    Id = "0",
                    Name = "SuperAdmin"
                },
                new IdentityRole
                {
                    Id = "1",
                    Name = "Basic"
                }
            };
        }
        private static List<IdentityUserRole<string>> IdentityUserRoleList()
        {
            return new List<IdentityUserRole<string>>()
            {
                new IdentityUserRole<string>
                {
                    RoleId = "1",
                    UserId = idGuid2
                },
                new IdentityUserRole<string>
                {
                    RoleId = "0",
                    UserId = idGuid
                }
            };
        }
        private static List<ApplicationUser> IdentityBasicUserList()
        {
            return new List<ApplicationUser>
            {
                new ApplicationUser
                {
                    Id = idGuid,
                    UserName = "superadmin",
                    Email = "superadmin@gmail.com",
                    FirstName = "Kaan",
                    LastName = "Celiker",
                    EmailConfirmed = true,
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = true,
                    PasswordHash = "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEBLjouNqaeiVWbN0TbXUS3+ChW3d7aQIk/BQEkWBxlrdRRngp14b0BIH0Rp65qD6mA==",
                },
                new ApplicationUser
                {
                    Id = idGuid2,
                    UserName = "basicuser",
                    Email = "basicuser@gmail.com",
                    FirstName = "Basic",
                    LastName = "User",
                    EmailConfirmed = true,
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = true,
                    PasswordHash = "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEBLjouNqaeiVWbN0TbXUS3+ChW3d7aQIk/BQEkWBxlrdRRngp14b0BIH0Rp65qD6mA==",
                },
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs :
**

```
using LinguaSphere.Core.Common;
using LinguaSphere.Core.Entities;
using LinguaSphere.CrossCuttingConcern.Identity;
using LinguaSphere.CrossCuttingConcern.OS;
using LinguaSphere.Persistence.Context.Seeds.Application;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace LinguaSphere.Persistence.Context
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : AuditableContext
    {
        private readonly ILoggedInUserService _loggedInUserService;
        private readonly IDateTimeProvider _dateTimeProvider;

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options,
            ILoggedInUserService loggedInUserService,
            IDateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider)
           : base(options)
        {
            ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
            _loggedInUserService = loggedInUserService;
            _dateTimeProvider = dateTimeProvider;
        }

        public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            foreach (var property in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
           .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
           .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(decimal) || p.ClrType == typeof(decimal?)))
            {
                property.SetColumnType("decimal(18,2)");
            }
            
            builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly);
            builder.ApplicationSeed();
        }

        public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<AuditableEntity>())
            {
                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        entry.Entity.CreatedBy = _loggedInUserService.UserId;
                        entry.Entity.DateCreated = _dateTimeProvider.UtcNow;
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        entry.Entity.ModifiedBy = _loggedInUserService.UserId;
                        entry.Entity.DateModified = _dateTimeProvider.UtcNow;
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (_loggedInUserService.UserId == null)
            {
                return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                return await base.SaveChangesAsync(_loggedInUserService.UserId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**AuditableContext.cs:
**

```
using LinguaSphere.Core.Entities;
using LinguaSphere.Core.Enum;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace LinguaSphere.Persistence.Context
{
    public class AuditableContext : IdentityContext
    {
        public AuditableContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }

        public DbSet<AuditTrail> AuditTrails { get; set; }

        public virtual async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(string userId = null)
        {
            var auditEntries = OnBeforeSaveChanges(userId);
            var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync();
            await OnAfterSaveChanges(auditEntries);
            return result;
        }

        private List<AuditEntry> OnBeforeSaveChanges(string userId)
        {
            ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
            var auditEntries = new List<AuditEntry>();
            foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
            {
                if (entry.Entity is AuditTrail || entry.State == EntityState.Detached || entry.State == EntityState.Unchanged)
                    continue;
                var auditEntry = new AuditEntry(entry);
                auditEntry.UserId = userId;
                auditEntries.Add(auditEntry);
                foreach (var property in entry.Properties)
                {
                    if (property.IsTemporary)
                    {
                        auditEntry.TemporaryProperties.Add(property);
                        continue;
                    }
                    string propertyName = property.Metadata.Name;
                    if (property.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey())
                    {
                        auditEntry.KeyValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                        continue;
                    }

                    switch (entry.State)
                    {
                        case EntityState.Added:
                            auditEntry.AuditType = AuditType.Create;
                            auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                            break;

                        case EntityState.Deleted:
                            auditEntry.AuditType = AuditType.Delete;
                            auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
                            break;

                        case EntityState.Modified:
                            if (property.IsModified)
                            {
                                auditEntry.ChangedColumns.Add(propertyName);
                                auditEntry.AuditType = AuditType.Update;
                                auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
                                auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (var auditEntry in auditEntries.Where(_ => !_.HasTemporaryProperties))
            {
                AuditTrails.Add(auditEntry.ToAudit());
            }
            return auditEntries.Where(_ => _.HasTemporaryProperties).ToList();
        }

        private Task OnAfterSaveChanges(List<AuditEntry> auditEntries)
        {
            if (auditEntries == null || auditEntries.Count == 0)
                return Task.CompletedTask;

            foreach (var auditEntry in auditEntries)
            {
                foreach (var prop in auditEntry.TemporaryProperties)
                {
                    if (prop.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey())
                    {
                        auditEntry.KeyValues[prop.Metadata.Name] = prop.CurrentValue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        auditEntry.NewValues[prop.Metadata.Name] = prop.CurrentValue;
                    }
                }
                AuditTrails.Add(auditEntry.ToAudit());
            }
            return SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

**IdentityContext.cs:
**

```
using LinguaSphere.Core.Entities;
using LinguaSphere.Persistence.Context.Seeds.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace LinguaSphere.Persistence.Context
{
    public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public IdentityContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            #region Tables
            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("User", "Identity");
            });
            builder.Entity<IdentityRole>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Role", "Identity");
            });
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("UserRoles", "Identity");
            });

            builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("UserClaims", "Identity");
            });

            builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("UserLogins", "Identity");
            });

            builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("RoleClaims", "Identity");
            });

            builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("UserTokens", "Identity");
            });
            #endregion
            
            builder.IdentitySeed();
        }
    }
}
```

**Roles.cs:
**

```
using System;
namespace LinguaSphere.Core.Enum
{
    public enum Roles
    {
        SuperAdmin = 0,
        Basic = 1
    }

    public static class Constants
    {
        public static readonly string SuperAdmin = "0";
        public static readonly string Basic = "1";

        public static readonly string SuperAdminUser = "0";
        public static readonly string BasicUser = "1";
    }
}
```

I tried to change guids to int or string.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just figured out that i need to seed the context with IdentityUser data.

```
private static List<IdentityUser> IdentityUserList()
    {
        return new List<IdentityUser>
        {
            new IdentityUser
            {
                Id = idGuid,
                UserName = "superadmin",
                Email = "superadmin@gmail.com",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = true,
                PasswordHash = "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEBLjouNqaeiVWbN0TbXUS3+ChW3d7aQIk/BQEkWBxlrdRRngp14b0BIH0Rp65qD6mA==",
            },
            new IdentityUser
            {
                Id = idGuid2,
                UserName = "basicuser",
                Email = "basicuser@gmail.com",
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = true,
                PasswordHash = "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEBLjouNqaeiVWbN0TbXUS3+ChW3d7aQIk/BQEkWBxlrdRRngp14b0BIH0Rp65qD6mA==",
            },
        };
    }
```